# How to show one back ground image sliding with few seconds difference in android like Lined_in mobile app

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager, slideshow

When I opens the app

1. show one image as back ground
2. After few seconds (automatically) move a bit and show same image moving right to left with text and click-able button on it

How to do that?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried when i open the app should able to get slide show of images but i want these images as back ground.

Comment: use Imageview for background images

Comment: @ling.s How to use it have you seen my requirement written above how to achieve it?

Comment: I want it just like shown in Linked-in mobile app.

Comment: post a link to Linked-in app

Comment: Linked-in-app link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.linkedin.android&hl=en

Comment: @ling.s
How to achieve it as shown in Linked-in app. If you have any idea let me know or give me any suggestions do achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Handler.postDelayed(); You can set different layout after few second using setContectView in run() method of Runnaable class which is used as a parameter in Handler.postDelayed().

Ex:

```
new Handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          setContectView(R.layout.secondlayout)
        }
    }, 2000);
```

This will load new layout after 2 seconds.

Comment: Thank you,I feel this is the simplified code than above mentioned code.

Answer (score 1):

May this help you

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        //display the logo during 5 secondes,
        new CountDownTimer(5*1000,1000){
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){} 

            @Override
            public void onFinish(){
                   //set the new Content of your activity
                   YourActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
            }
       }.start();
    }
```

Comment: Here the second image appearing directly after 5seconds. How can i show next layout slowly (like left to right slide) can we set the time for it.

Comment: for that purpose you will be use animation.....
for animation follow the link below...
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/

Comment: How to show sliding just like Linked-in mobile app.If you know let me know or give me any suggestions